# SQL group by within sum()

Tags: sql, sum

I have the following sql statement which produces the following output (filtered result for 7/8 DueDate)

```
SELECT
    JobType.BillingCategory,
    Jobs.DueDate,
    Sum(Impressions.PRINTtot) AS SumOfPRINTtot,
    Sum(Impressions.PRINTrem) AS SumOfPRINTrem,
    Sum(Impressions.CARDtot) AS SumOfCARDtot,
    Sum(Impressions.CARDrem) AS SumOfCARDrem,
    Sum(Impressions.BOOKtot) AS SumOfBOOKtot,
    Sum(Impressions.BOOKrem) AS SumOfBOOKrem
FROM
    (
        Impressions
        INNER JOIN Jobs ON Impressions.JobNo = Jobs.JobNo
    )
    INNER JOIN JobType ON (Jobs.AccountName = JobType.AccountName)
    AND (Jobs.Product = JobType.Product)
GROUP BY
    Jobs.DueDate,
    JobType.BillingCategory;
```

[image]

I am trying to get all of these results on one line: the identifier would be the DueDate and the sums of the values in the Impressions table would be summed for each BillingCategory.  Example below (omitting CARD & BOOK sums just for visual purposes w/ too many columns)

[image]

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @ggordon SQL - i just have a linked table in access and copied the data to excel for a visual

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CASE expression to summarize your data as such. You could modify your query to sum for only that billing category, I have used `CARD` in the example below to summarize the metrics for `Impressions.PRINTtot` and `SumOfPRINTrem`

```sql
SELECT
    Jobs.DueDate,
    Sum(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARD' THEN Impressions.PRINTtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTtotCard,
    Sum(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARD' THEN Impressions.PRINTrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTremCard,
    ....<repeat>
FROM
    (
        Impressions
        INNER JOIN Jobs ON Impressions.JobNo = Jobs.JobNo
    )
    INNER JOIN JobType ON (Jobs.AccountName = JobType.AccountName)
    AND (Jobs.Product = JobType.Product)
GROUP BY
    Jobs.DueDate
```

**Edit 1:**
Based on the Billing Categories listed in your question

A complete example may look like:

```sql
SELECT

    Jobs.DueDate,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARD' THEN Impressions.PRINTtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTtotCARD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARD' THEN Impressions.PRINTrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTremCARD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARD' THEN Impressions.CARDtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfCARDtotCARD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARD' THEN Impressions.CARDrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfCARDremCARD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARD' THEN Impressions.BOOKtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfBOOKtotCARD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARD' THEN Impressions.BOOKrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfBOOKremCARD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARDTIPON' THEN Impressions.PRINTtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTtotCARDTIPON,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARDTIPON' THEN Impressions.PRINTrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTremCARDTIPON,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARDTIPON' THEN Impressions.CARDtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfCARDtotCARDTIPON,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARDTIPON' THEN Impressions.CARDrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfCARDremCARDTIPON,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARDTIPON' THEN Impressions.BOOKtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfBOOKtotCARDTIPON,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='CARDTIPON' THEN Impressions.BOOKrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfBOOKremCARDTIPON,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='EOB' THEN Impressions.PRINTtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTtotEOB,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='EOB' THEN Impressions.PRINTrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTremEOB,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='EOB' THEN Impressions.CARDtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfCARDtotEOB,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='EOB' THEN Impressions.CARDrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfCARDremEOB,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='EOB' THEN Impressions.BOOKtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfBOOKtotEOB,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='EOB' THEN Impressions.BOOKrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfBOOKremEOB,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDE' THEN Impressions.PRINTtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTtotMEMBERGUIDE,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDE' THEN Impressions.PRINTrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTremMEMBERGUIDE,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDE' THEN Impressions.CARDtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfCARDtotMEMBERGUIDE,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDE' THEN Impressions.CARDrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfCARDremMEMBERGUIDE,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDE' THEN Impressions.BOOKtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfBOOKtotMEMBERGUIDE,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDE' THEN Impressions.BOOKrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfBOOKremMEMBERGUIDE,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDEHD' THEN Impressions.PRINTtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTtotMEMBERGUIDEHD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDEHD' THEN Impressions.PRINTrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfPRINTremMEMBERGUIDEHD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDEHD' THEN Impressions.CARDtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfCARDtotMEMBERGUIDEHD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDEHD' THEN Impressions.CARDrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfCARDremMEMBERGUIDEHD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDEHD' THEN Impressions.BOOKtot ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfBOOKtotMEMBERGUIDEHD,
SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='MEMBERGUIDEHD' THEN Impressions.BOOKrem ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfBOOKremMEMBERGUIDEHD

FROM
    (
        Impressions
        INNER JOIN Jobs ON Impressions.JobNo = Jobs.JobNo
    )
    INNER JOIN JobType ON (Jobs.AccountName = JobType.AccountName)
    AND (Jobs.Product = JobType.Product)
GROUP BY
    Jobs.DueDate
```

With a specific database/tool there may be various functions that may prove useful. However, I find in these cases especially since your billing categories may change over time, a script where you can run anywhere is sometimes helpful. I've included the script I used to generate the code below

```js
var types='CARD,CARDTIPON,EOB,MEMBERGUIDE,MEMBERGUIDEHD'.split(',');
var metrics = metrics='PRINTtot,PRINTrem,CARDtot,CARDrem,BOOKtot,BOOKrem'.split(',');
var metricTemplate="SUM(CASE WHEN JobType.BillingCategory='[TYPE]' THEN Impressions.[METRICNAME] ELSE 0 END) AS SumOf[METRICNAME][TYPE]";

var summary_lines = []
for(var i=0;i < types.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<metrics.length;j++){
       summary_lines.push(metricTemplate.replaceAll('[TYPE]',types[i]).replaceAll('[METRICNAME]',metrics[j]))
    }
}

complete_metrics = summary_lines.join(",\n");

console.log(complete_metrics)
```

Comment: Yep, you beat me.

Comment: Column 'JobType.BillingCategory' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Rick this has been updated along with another helpful bit of code. I hope this helps.

Comment: @ggordon need to remove billingcategory from the select - looks to be working!  thank you

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to use your query as a CTE (Common Table Expression) and then you can use it as a base for another query.

For example:

```
with
q as (
  -- your query here
)
select
  max(DueDate) as DueDate,
  sum(case when BillingCategory = 'CARD' then SumOfPRINTtot else 0 end) as SumOfPRINTtotC,
  sum(case when BillingCategory = 'CARD' then SumOfPRINTrem else 0 end) as SumOfPRINTremC,
  sum(case when BillingCategory = 'CARDTIPON' then SumOfPRINTtot else 0 end) as SumOfPRINTtotCT,
  sum(case when BillingCategory = 'CARDTIPON' then SumOfPRINTrem else 0 end) as SumOfPRINTremCT,
  sum(case when BillingCategory = 'EOB' then SumOfPRINTtot else 0 end) as SumOfPRINTtotE,
  sum(case when BillingCategory = 'EOB' then SumOfPRINTrem else 0 end) as SumOfPRINTremE,
  sum(case when BillingCategory = 'MEMBERGUIDE' then SumOfPRINTtot else 0 end) as SumOfPRINTtotMG,
  sum(case when BillingCategory = 'MEMBERGUIDE' then SumOfPRINTrem else 0 end) as SumOfPRINTremMG,
  sum(case when BillingCategory = 'MEMBERGUIDEHD' then SumOfPRINTtot else 0 end) as SumOfPRINTtotMGH,
  sum(case when BillingCategory = 'MEMBERGUIDEHD' then SumOfPRINTrem else 0 end) as SumOfPRINTremMGH
from q
```

In some databases you can use the `FILTER` clause as well. You don't mention which specific database, so this solution will work on virtually all databases.